# How to develop a android unlock screen app

Tags: android

I am student and I want to develop a android unlock screen app. I want to know what android api can give me some helps and how can I set my app as the default unlock screen app. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to unlock or lock the screen?

Comment: I want to develop a software that can be used as a unlock screen app.

Comment: I bet now we can ask this once again ? ) im interested in answer. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported by the Android SDK today, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean that I can't develop my own screen unlock app? But I knew that there are third party screen unlock apps. How they work? Thank you for your help.

Comment: They usually do it with hacks that are unlikely to work from device to device or Android platform version to version.

Comment: @Jerome: "You mean that I can't develop my own screen unlock app?" -- correct." But I knew that there are third party screen unlock apps." -- no, there aren't. There are various pieces of software using malware techniques that prohibit access to their device. They are not official screen locks, which is only possible via firmware modifications.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old. But just to help anyone seeing this post aand getting disheartened, I've found an answer on a comparable question on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above), it might help now. There is also a new feature named `DayDream` in the API 4.2 this could be also interesting. It's a feature.

Hope it helps someone. Cheers :)