# Android voice recognition for unlocking phones

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I m doing project on android voice recognition for security purpose.The user of phone should be able to unlock phone with his/her voice.I need some help on this.The user needs to first save it voice sample in device so that next time he/she want to unlock, it would prompt for their voice i/p.One more thing is the app should be initialized after user restarts the phone.
First of all whether its possible ? Till now i have done with voice recognition using(TTS(text to speech))it gives you the hints of what u said. i mean can we edit android lock screen ?Need Help !! thank you

Comment: First of all whether its possible ?
Till now i have done with voice recognition using(TTS(text to speech))it gives you the hints of what u said.
i mean can we edit android lock screen ?

Comment: in order to get a answer i suggest you add that to your question.

Comment: there is no real way of doing that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840661/how-to-develop-a-android-unlock-screen-app

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is already solved by this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mah.voicepassword ask it's author.