# developing an android lock screen application

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to develop my own lock screen for Android that will replace the default android lock screen. I do not have any idea how to start.

Is there any tutorial about it or an example I can download and open in my eclipse and run ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You may check my answer, I think will help you achieve what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/3300883

Comment: I wrote a post about How to write simple Android Lock Screen: http://www.thedroidboy.com/how-to-write-simple-android-lock-screen/

Answer (score 16):

What you actually want to do is create an application which will look like the home screen and prevent the "real" home screen from appearing.

You might want to have a look at this:
[Launcher2.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git)

I would also recommend reading these questions:

[Create custom lockscreen for android 4.0 or above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own

Comment: You can use the [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia.com)