# Independent lock screen for the Android APP

Tags: android, android-layout, locking, lockscreen

Does anyone knows how to implement lock screen for the app? 
If we open the app, it should ask the password first to enter into the home screen. And i also i want, if the app is in resume or pause state when ever it comes to foreground it should ask password to enter.

Sorry for my english. It would be great if anyone can help me or refer me with any sample code.

Thanks In advance. 
[image: lock screen]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [lock screen development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207690/developing-an-android-lock-screen-application) .I expected that you will be get help from link. Best of Luck!