# Create custom LockScreen for Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a custom lockscreen for Android version 7.1.1. (Nougat). I know that there are a lot answers on how to create a custom lockscreen, but whatever code I try to use, it's not really working.

The problem appears because of using deprecated methods. The app crushes, and there are no methods to replace the deprecated ones.

Does anyone know a way that this still works?

These are some of the links I've tried to use (there were a few older ones also but I didn't save them):

[how to make our own lock screen in android instead of default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598612/how-to-make-our-own-lock-screen-in-android-instead-of-default-lock-screen)

https://github.com/thomasvidas/Simple-Lockscreen/tree/master

[developing an android lock screen application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207690/developing-an-android-lock-screen-application)

[Create custom lockscreen for android 4.0 or above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above)

Comment: Provide all links that you have tried so we don't suggest something that you've already tried.

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I managed to make this app working. My biggest problem was to put my device in kiosk mode (disabling hardware buttons when the lockscreen is displayed). The solution that worked for me was enabling device owner mode using Android Debug Bridge. It wasn't the best solution, but it was the most acceptable one for this project.

Here are some of the links that I used to achieve this:

https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Device_Enrollment/Enabling_Device_Owner_Mode_using_Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)

http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/