# Qt Android How to Develop Lock Screen App

Tags: android, qt, qml, lockscreen

Nowadays, I am trying to develop a screen app by using Qt Android.
I have developed some parts of it (GUI and image process etc.) with QML and Javascript.
But, when I search for some documents about Lock Screen App in Qt, I cannot find any thing.

Is there a way to develop Android App for Lock Screen in Qt or not?

If possible, what is the API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create custom lockscreen for android 4.0 or above?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above)

Comment: I want it in QT(C++)

Comment: I missed that, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps this is not possible with pure Qt. You probably have to write some Android-specific code (with Java, even?), to get your Qt app work as lock screen. If nobody can write actual answer, I'd look into that direction.