# Android:does current android SDK support developing an unlock app?

Tags: java, android, google-play, unlock

I want to make an unlock app for android, I read that about 2 years ago it has not been supported by the android SDK of that time (mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840732/1986618). Is it possible now? If not, what is the way to do that as you can see lots of these unlock apps on Market?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a answer on a compareable question on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above), may that helps.
There is also a new feature named [DayDream](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) in the API 4.2 this could be also interesting for you. It's a feature.
In addtion when you look at the section Lockscreen Widget you may find a hint to get access to the lockscreen itself.

Hope that helps

Greetings